# Why don't unexpandable active characters work in \csname...\endcsname?

Tags: tex-core, expansion, csname, active-characters

Page 213 of The TeXbook has a definitive explanation of `\csname...\endcsname`:

> When TeX expands `\csname` it reads to the matching `\endcsname`,
> expanding tokens as it goes; only character tokens should remain
> after this expansion has taken place. […]

I noticed that active characters can be made unexpandable by giving a definition like

```
\chardef~="16
```

Then `~` will stand for itself in commands like `\message{~}` and `\edef\foo{~}`. But why doesn't `\csname~\endcsname` work?

Answer (score 8):

A `\chardef` token is not a character, but a command to *print* a character.

As such, it is not allowed inside `\csname...\endcsname` where only *character* tokens (after macro expansion) are permitted.

The fact that `\edef\foo{~}` yields `~` is because a `\chardef` token is unexpandable. Similarly for `\message{~}`.

The fact that TeX assigns special internal codes to active characters is irrelevant. The relevant aspect is whether an active character's definition is a macro or not. If it is a macro, it is expanded; otherwise it isn't and it's behavior depends on the context.

So, for instance, if you have

```
\chardef~="16
\csname\ifnum~="16 \string~\else foo\fi\endcsname
```

is perfectly good and would end up with `\~`. But it's not really "using `~` inside `\csname...\endcsname`, of course.

On the other hand, `\&` is defined by `\chardef\&="26` and `\&` is *not* allowed ”naked” inside `\csname...\endcsname`, exactly like `~` would be if it's a `\chardef` token.

Another similar problem is with implicit character tokens. If you do

```
\let~=a
```

you're *not* allowed to use `~` inside `\csname...\endcsname` as well.

Comment: Characters and commands are not contradictory. Ordinary characters like `L` are also commands when passed to TeX’s “stomach”, according to page 267 of The TeXbook.

Comment: @HuYajie The first sentence is about `\chardef` tokens not being character tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Page 47 of *The TeXbook* states that

> If TeX sees a character of categories 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 11, 12, or 13, or a character
> of category 7 that is not the first of a special sequence as just described, it
> converts the character to a token by attaching the category code, and goes into state *M*.

but this is a white lie. Characters of category 13 are actually converted to a special kind of control sequences by the following code in tex.web:

> **353**. ⟨ Process an active-character control sequence and set *state* ← *mid_line* 353 ⟩ ≡
>   **begin** *cur_cs* ← *cur_chr* + *active_base*; *cur_cmd* ← *eq_type*(*cur_cs*); *cur_chr* ← *equiv*(*cur_cs*);
>   *state* ← *mid_line*;
>   **if** *cur_cmd* ≥ *outer_call* **then** *check_outer_validity*;
>   **end**

The variable *cur_cs* is 0 for character tokens, 1–256 for active characters of character code 0–255, and > 256 for real control sequences. Unfortunately, the code in ⟨ Manufacture a control sequence name 372 ⟩ only accepts tokens with *cur_cs* = 0 when collecting characters for the `\csname...\endcsname` construction.

`\message{~}` and `\edef\foo{~}` work essentially like `\message{\$}` and `\edef\foo{\$}`.

Comment: The last line seems wrong, `\message{~}` shows ~ as you say in the question (if it is a chardef token) but that is not essentially like \message{\undefined} (which gives an undefined command error)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, fixed. I probably meant something like `\unexpandable`.

Comment: The sentence you quoted from The TeXbook isn't a white lie as you describe it: active characters and even control sequences are tokens too (e.g. `\relax` is a single token), so the quoted sentence seems accurate (`~` is a token, just one with nonzero `cur_cs`). I think you need to look elsewhere in the TeXbook to see what's documented about `\csname … \endcsname` .

Comment: @ShreevatsaR The white lie is the “attaching the category code” part. Active characters like `~` are stored as tokens, but not in the form of (character code, category code) pairs.